# join with same table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Im having the following table , each employee have a manager, if a guy is his own manager den the managerid field is null, i want `emid name and manager id` as result table name is employee

```
emid name managerid
1    raj  null
2    ram   1
3    ravi   null
4    arvind  3
5    rithu   2
```

and i want the result as

```
emid name managername
1    raj  raj
2    ram   raj
3    ravi   ravi
4    arvind  ravi
5    rithu   ram
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT e1.emid, e1.name, COALESCE(e2.name, e1.name) AS managername
    FROM employee e1
        LEFT JOIN employee e2
            ON e1.managerid = e2.emid
```

Comment: Stefanelli : thank you this is what i exactly want, m hearing first time about COALESC , googling that now, can you explainn tht

Comment: @kiran: `COALESCE` will return the first non-null argument in the list, or NULL if all the arguments are NULL. mysql documentation for it is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

Answer (score 1):

UNTESTED:

```
select a.name as name, b.name as managername from employee a inner join employee b on a.managerid=b.emid
```

This will only yield the employees who actually have a manager. But this is how you join a table on itself.

Comment: but how can i get the name for those null values

Comment: Joe Stefanelli posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
      e1.emid,
      e1.name,
      COALESCE(e2.name, e1.name ) ManagerName
   from 
      employees e1
         left join employees e2
            on e1.managerid = e2.emid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT emid, name,
       CASE WHEN s.managerid IS NULL THEN s.name ELSE m.name END managername
  FROM employees s
  LEFT JOIN employees m ON s.managerid = m.managerid
```

OR

```
SELECT emid, name, m.name managername
  FROM employees s
  LEFT JOIN employees m ON COALESCE(s.managerid, s.emid) = m.emid
```