# MySql Join on Same Table

Tags: mysql

I'm a novice when it comes to sql so forgive me if this seems obvious.

I've looked over all the answers that I've found here and tried to adapt them to work with my data but for some reason the results are never correct.

I simply want to extract the data in an ordered list with parents (records with 0 for parent_id) with each ones siblings underneath it.

I can't post images yet as i've not been a member long enough but my table structure is quite simple.

```
id, subject, parent_id
```

Subjects that are parents have a parent_id of zero.

Thanks

Steve

PS: I tried this solution but it didn't work correctly for me. [join with same table in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127366/join-with-same-table-in-mysql)

Comment: what is desired output from this table ? can u explain ?

Comment: I want all the subjects returned by grouped by parent_id. Parents have parent_id of zero so It would be something like parent1->first child of parent1 -> second child of parent1. This would be repeated for all parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT p.subject AS parent, 
group_concat(c.subject) AS children 
FROM yourtable AS p 
LEFT JOIN yourtable AS c 
ON (p.id = c.parent_id and p.parent_id = 0) 
GROUP BY p.id;`
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion but it didn't return any data. Just an empty recordset.

Comment: Oh wait, sorry, had a typo in the join condition. Try it now.

Comment: I changed your suggestions a little and it kind of worked but it didn't return a parent with no children. `select p.subject as parent, group_concat(c.subject) as children from subjects as p join subjects as c on (p.id = c.parent_id and p.parent_id = 0) group by p.id`

Comment: Your suggestion is the closest so far but it doesn't return parents with no children.

Comment: Ah, then you want to use a left join. I've modified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**EXACT AND AS REQUIRED**

```
select s1.id, s2.name from tab1 s1 LEFT JOIN tab1 s2 on s1.id = s2.parent
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but that didn't work. It just pulled back 3 parents and one of them was a duplicate.

Comment: @user1292262 Hey, i've updated answer check it out, i've tested it, now it's working fine

Comment: I changed your suggestions a little and it kind of worked but it didn't return a parent with no children. `select p.subject as parent, group_concat(c.subject) as children from subjects as p join subjects as c on (p.id = c.parent_id and p.parent_id = 0) group by p.id`

Comment: sorry that was to the person below